# Multiple forms in one page in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have one blade page has one form to update and another one to save

my question How i can submit both according to method type

I tried to achieve that like the following example

```
 public function postCompanyProfileSettings(Request $request)
 {

    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
          // do something to save
      }
     if($request->isMethod('PUT')) {
        // do something to update 
     }
 }
```

it's working well with POST  method but with PUT return Route Exception `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

I think that the issue in routs.php but  i don't know what exactly to do to handle one route for multiple forms (multiple methods)

My route in route.php file

```
  //setting routes...
 get('/home/settings', 'CompanyProfileController@getCompanyProfileSettings');
 post('/home/settings','CompanyProfileController@postCompanyProfileSettings');
```

**Do there is any way to achieve that?**

Comment: Where is the put method in your route?

Comment: @aldrin27: this is my ques  i don't know what exactly to do to handle one route for multiple forms (multiple methods)

**Do there is any way to achieve that?**

Comment: Try this: `Route::match(['get', 'post', 'put'], '/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});` Match your route. Read this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: @aldrin27: thanks for help now it's working

Comment: No biggie :D Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a hidden input

```
 public function postCompanyProfileSettings(Request $request)
 {

    if(isset($request->get('update')) {
          // do something to update
      }
      // do something to save  
 }
```

And routes..

```
post('/home/settings','CompanyProfileController@postCompanyProfileSettings');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion i'll use the same method which is POST.

1st form:

```
<form method="POST" action={{ url('vault/{batch_centre_id}/candidates/{id}', ['form' => '1']) }}>
```

2nd form:

```
<form method="POST" action={{ url('vault/{batch_centre_id}/candidates/{id}', ['form' => '2']) }}>
```

in your action check form:

```
if ($request->get('form') == 1) {
return $request->get('form');
} else if ($request->get('form') == 2) {
return $request->get('form');
}

return result;
```

So from the above you can have unlimited forms on a single page so long you tag your forms and verify them from your controller.

Check this [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/two-forms-one-page)